# jscript runtime error

Tags: jscript

I have a visual studio 2010 project.  It runs from my notebook fine but from my desktop it won't run.  The error is Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined.  Here is the code

```
function fadeDiv() {
   $(function () {        
      $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblStatus').fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
});};
```

this machine had visual studio on it, but i had to remove it and reinstall it again because the silverlight SDK had issue.  It has been working fine now for a couple of weeks until this code was inserted into our asp.net code using .net 4.0.  I've run sfc /scannow and it reported no errors.  I've also rebooted.  The Jscript file exists amongst other places in c:\windows\system32.  This is a windows 7 machine 64 bit.  The machine is fully patched.  the jscript file that is on my machine in c:\windows\system32 is version 5.8.7601.16982 and 799 KB.anyway.. sure hope someone can help me outthanksshannon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $ variable is used in a couple libraries - most popularly JQuery. It is not Vanilla Javascript. Try including the JQuery script at the top of your code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```